# Not able to create folders in integration services catalog SQL Server 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

Not able to create folders in integration services catalog SSIS 2012

Error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Is your system under memory constraints? Has something changed recently (patches, maintenance, etc)?

Comment: We recently restored the entire server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i can create folder in Catalogs

Resolve:

Check the login       :##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##

[image]

that needs to be enabled Database RoleMembership for: SSISDB as public

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the restore is the issue.

When you create your SSISDB, you specify a password which is used to create your database master key. You have restored the database to a different server and you need to get the keys in alignment on the restored machine

BOL covers this in detail: [Backup, Restore, and Move the SSIS Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213291.aspx)

```
   -- If you know what the password that was used when the catalog was created
   open master key 
   decryption by password = 'LS1Setup!' --'Password used when creating SSISDB'
   Alter Master Key 
   Add encryption by Service Master Key
```

Otherwise, you're going to need to use a hammer.

```
   Restore master key from file = 'c:\temp\RCTestInstKey'
   Decryption by password = 'LS2Setup!' -- 'Password used to encrypt the master key during SSISDB backup'
   Encryption by password = 'LS3Setup!' -- 'New Password'
   Force
```

Comment: We are facing the issue at the time of deploying SSIS package. The error message is given below

"Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation"

Comment: Why does we actually give the password while creation of SSIS Catalog... what does it actually mean

Comment: @koushikveldanda It sounds like you have a question - why don't you post it as a question

Comment: I have reached my limit of asking questions can you please tell the answer @billinkc

Comment: @koushikveldanda That should be telling you that you need to try to help yourself, rather than relying on other people. Try doing some research.

Comment: @koushikveldanda what are you talking about? Your last question was in 2015, What limit?